# How to read a text file from within Django view function?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in one of my view functions:

```
def results(request):
    data_file = open('data.txt', 'r')       
    data = data_file.read()
    context = {'rooms': data}
    return render(request, 'javascript/results.html',context)
```

The file 'data.txt' is located in the same folder as my "views.py".

However, I am getting "FileNotFoundError at /results" error.

My 'results.html' looks like this:

```
<p> {{ rooms }}</p>
```

What is the correct way to pass data from a text file to a Django view function, and then display the data in the template? Should I use static files instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try giving the full path to the text file.

**EX:**

```
import os

def results(request):
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'data.txt')   #full path to text.
    data_file = open(file_path , 'r')       
    data = data_file.read()
    context = {'rooms': data}
    return render(request, 'javascript/results.html',context)
```

Comment: This doesn't work with python3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def result(request)
    emails = []
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'disposable.txt')
    disposable_mails = open(file_path, 'r+')
    for disposable_mail in disposable_mails:
        emails.append(disposable_mail.rstrip())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).