# GET request 404 error (not found) this is the error that i am getting when i am calling a file present in same folder

Tags: python, html, django, ajax, get

This is the javascript code in which I am using the get method.

[image: 1]

This is the directory in which both the files are present, the html file that the js code is part of and also the text file.
This is the image of the console with errors.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: when you use xhr.open('GET','text.txt',true)  the second argument 'text.txt' should be a url that is why django tries to tell you there is no url called 'text.txt'

Comment: the solution for this to try to create a view that reads the 'text.tx' and displays the data.and after that replace  this xhr.open('GET','text.txt',true) to xhr.open('GET','***the url of that view***',true). if you really need to use a very clean way you can try Jquery (get) you can read it here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

Comment: Please don't include code as image

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to read the contents of "text.txt" file. However this isn't how it would work.
You first need to create a view / view url in django which will read the file for you.
This is how the process should ideally work:

1. Your javascript code will send a request to this view / view url
2. Your view will read the contents of the file and return the contents to your javascript
3. Use the javascript to render content

To create a view see the link:
[Read text file from Django view function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207179/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-within-django-view-function)


As mentioned in the comments use jQuery for a clean way of fetching and then rendering information:
[jQuery Get and Post](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)